# SSRS Chart with crosshair

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am trying use SSRS as a reporting solution and love all the features like scheduling and export to various formats that comes with it. But I want to also have interactive charts and wonder whether SSRS can do that. I don't think it can do it natively but does any one knows an add in or a workaround? 
I am trying to achieve something like below ? 
http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!line-chart-with-crosshair-tooltips

Many thanks.
V

Comment: What do you mean by "interactive charts"?  Displaying popup data on rollover?

Answer (score 2):

As you said SSRS doesn't support this sort of interactions natively, it is very limited about to presentation and HTML customization, also interaction via JavaScript is *almost* null.

**Dundas** offers third-party controls to create great visualization but I am unsure about using Dundas MS Integration you can create the specific visualization you need.

**Telerik** offers another product to integrate with SSRS and create custom visualization.

**Technologies offered by Microsoft:**

Also if you own a SQL Server Enterprise license you may want to use **Datazen**, a fantastic alternative to SSRS to create interactive visualizations compatible with multiple platforms and devices. **PowerBI** is another option you have to create interactive dashboards and reports.